# Possible to create a two player client-server game in one application?

Tags: java, android, networking, client

I'm creating a battleships type game for android. I don't have suitable device(s) so I'm using 2 instances of the emulator but only one project. I have the basic mechanics working but what is a good structure to use for the networking so that different things show on each emulator?

For example if player 1 hits player 2 on square D2 it would only be visibly destroyed on one screen. will I need multiple activities? How would I differentiate between emulators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one, you will need some sort of server to handle the connections between players. That server could then designate which player is which within a game. I'm not sure exactly what answer you are looking for--a proper answer would have to include the entire architecture for a multiplayer game.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was really just asking if it was possible to have this kind of tcp/ip setup without any physical devices or multiple projects. I haven't been able to find any examples of that online.

Comment: At some point, the clients can identify themselves with a server using some random number. The server can then track each instance separately.